# Sanitizing some values in MySQL Wordpress wp_postmeta table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

In my wordpress mysql database I've the in `wp_postmeta` table most rows with `meta_key='price'`.

In that rows the meta_value should be a number, but I've different things:

1. 10.000 (means ten thousand because in europe the dot stands for thousand)
2. 100,00 (means one hundred)
3. free (or other text)
4. 100-500 (means a price from 100 to 500)
5. 100/500 (same as above)

I would like to sanitize this situation by:

- removing all the dot from the numbers so to have a pure number
- removing all the commas because I don't need the decimals
- delete all the words, except only "free"
- remove the second value from the values with a range (like the ones in point 4 and 5), also by removing the / or -

How is it possible to do that? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Step 0: backup your database!

Comment: hihi thanks biziclop for your suggest, but I'm already working on a copy of my database